# Разница между уснуть и заснуть

Tags: грамотная-речь

Разница уснуть и заснуть?

Comment: @Шумкар, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Существенной разницы междыу этими словами нет. Значение приставок У- и ЗА- здесь одинаковое- завершение действия. Сравните две словарные статьи из словаря Д.Н. Ушакова:

УСНУ́ТЬ, усну, уснёшь, совер.
1. Заснуть. «До места барку дотянул и богатырским сном уснул.» Некрасов. «Уснул, потрудившийся в поте!» Некрасов. «Прикорнув к спинкам диванов, стараются уснуть.» Чехов.
|| перен. Затихнуть, замереть, прекратиться (поэт.). «О, бурь уснувших не буди.» Тютчев. «- Уснуло озеро. Безмолвен тихий лес.» Фет. «Он думы разбудил, уснувшие во мне.» Пушкин.
2. Умереть, стать снулой (о рыбе). Рыба без воды уснула.
❖ Уснуть навеки или вечным сном (поэт.) - умереть.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

ЗАСНУ́ТЬ, засну, заснёшь, совер. (к засыпать1). Погрузиться в сон.
|| перен. Замереть, затихнуть (книжн.).
❖ Заснуть вечным сном (книжн. ритор.) - умереть.

Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.

Answer (score 3):

В словарях говорится о том, что глаголы "заснуть и уснуть" одинаковы по значению: он уснул или он заснул, нет разницы. Но приставки-то у глаголов разные, да и область применения не всегда совпадает.

Уснуть - это погрузиться в сон, приставка У обозначает полноту совершенного действия. А глагол "заснуть" обозначает начало сна, видовая пара: засыпать - заснуть, приставка ЗА в глаголе совершенного вида.

"О, бурь уснувших не буди". Здесь, например, можно использовать только глагол "уснуть".

Comment: А как понять, какой из глаголов может использоваться в каком случае?